# Characters of the absolute Galois group and their restrictions

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

I am reading this paper [Cremona et. al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.12103.pdf). In section 3 (pages 5-6), they talk about characters more specifically about Dirichlet characters and characters of the absolute Galois group, $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$. I am a little lost probably because my background is not strong enough.

I have a couple of questions that I got stuck on were:

1. How to think of characters over $\mathbb{Q}$ as characters of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$?
2. How does a character of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ restricts to a number field $K$ ?

Could someone recommend a resource to learn about these things?  Should I be reading about Galois representations?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1. For a finite image (equivalently continuous in the relevant topologies) character $$\rho : Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty)/\Bbb{Q})\to \Bbb{C}^\times$$ Then the subfield fixed by $\ker(\rho)$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ (of degree $|Image(\rho)|$). Thus for some
     $k$, $\ker(\rho)$ contains $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty)/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_k))$ and hence $\rho$ is a character $$Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_k)/\Bbb{Q})\cong \Bbb{Z}/k \Bbb{Z}^\times\to \Bbb{C}^\times$$  A character $$f:\Bbb{Z}/k \Bbb{Z}^\times\to \Bbb{C}^\times$$ corresponds to a Dirichlet character: $\chi(n)= f(n)$ if $\gcd(n,k)=1$, otherwise $\chi(n)=0$.

     Conversely any Dirichlet character gives a character $\Bbb{Z}/k \Bbb{Z}^\times\to \Bbb{C}^\times$ for some $k$ thus a character $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_k)/\Bbb{Q})\to \Bbb{C}^\times$ and hence a continuous character $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})\to \Bbb{C}^\times$.

     The correspondence is not one-to-one, it is if we take the minimum possible $k$ and restrict to the primitive Dirichlet characters.

     Any character $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})\to \Bbb{C}^\times$ factorizes through the abelianization of $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$ which is $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty)/\Bbb{Q})$ (Kronecker Weber theorem).
- 2. You probably meant restricting a character $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})\to \Bbb{C}^\times$ to a character  $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/K)\to \Bbb{C}^\times$.

     The continuous characters $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/K)\to \Bbb{C}^\times$ correspond similarly to the finite image Hecke characters of $K$, but this is a much more complicated story, the theorems from class field theory.

Comment: Can you please clarify what $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q})_{\infty}$ is? Is this the union of towers of cyclotomic extension of the form $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$ ?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})$ : adding all the roots of unity to $\Bbb{Q}$. Adding the power-of-2-roots of unity would be $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^\infty})$. There is also $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^\infty-1})$ (the roots of unity of order coprime with $2$)